# Como guardar datos de un loop en un archivos cvs, en python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, raspberry-pi

Siendo sincero aun me falta bastante camino por recorrer en python y en la programación aun me considero en etapa de aprendizaje, intento guardar la información de mi loop en un archivo csv y que este se refresque, en este caso quiero guardar la hora y la fecha en una variable llamada hora y que este programa no pare hasta que se mate el proceso, mientras tanto la informacion de la variable se refresca cada 3 segundos y se va guardando en un csv, por lo menos eso pretendo este es mi codigo:

```
import datetime  # Librerias para el tiempo y la fecha :p
import time
import csv

hora = datetime.datetime.now()  # En esta variable guardamos la fecha y hora actual

# En este while imprimimos las variables en un ciclo con un dalay de 0.3 segundos :D para que no se sature la memoria
parar = 0
while (parar == 0):
    print(hora)
    time.sleep(0.3)

ltiempo = [hora]

f = open("horas.csv", "w")
writer = csv.DictWriter(
    f, fieldnames=[ltiempo])
writer.writeheader()
f.close()
```

**¿Como logro que se genere el csv y que errores cometi, ya que aunque no me marca error no me crea ningun archivo ni me guarda los valores de la variable U.U?**
les agradeceré bastante sus sugerencias y correcciones :D!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca sales del while, la variable 'parar' nunca toma un valor distinto a 0
Además debes quitar los corchetes [] en la asignación a fieldnames
0.3 no son 3 segundos, son 3 décimas de segundo.

Quedaría así,

```
import datetime  # Librerias para el tiempo y la fecha :p
import time
import csv

hora = datetime.datetime.now()  # En esta variable guardamos la fecha y hora actual

# En este while imprimimos las variables en un ciclo con un dalay de 0.3 segundos :D para que no se sature la memoria
parar = 10
ltiempo = []
while (parar > 0):
    print(hora)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    ltiempo.append(hora)
    parar -=1

f = open("horas.csv", "w")
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=ltiempo)
writer.writeheader()
f.close()
```